# Altcoin Wallet based on Litecoin source

Tags: wallet, altcoin, litecoin

I create my own altcoin based on litecoin source version 0.15 . I have any seed seted,but i have in wallet config addnode=ip. Why my wallet don t sync with blockchain ? It sync if i mine.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how many blocks you mined and how many wallets are connected?Mining is how the wallets get synced and if no one mines..there will be no syncing between the wallets.

Comment: 1 wallet , 4 block s on wallet 8 on daemon